# Fork Implementation using C library functions setcontext(), getcontext() etc

Tags: c++, multithreading, unix, pthreads

I am writing a custom user-level thread library using he C functions *getcontext(), setcontext()*, and *makecontext()*. I am having difficulty in the implementing logic of thread_fork() function. Basically, thread_fork() function creates new thread and when returns from thread_fork(), newly created thread should receive a return value of **0** while the original thread should receive the **threadid** as return value.

```
void Thread1Example(int) {
  std::cout << "B" << std::endl;
  thread_exit();
}
void main() {
  Init(); // Initialize thread library data structures
  std::cout << "A" << std::endl;
  int thread1 = thread_fork(); // Fork a new thread and returns 0 & threadID
  if (thread1==0)
    Thread1Example();
  std::cout << "C" << std::endl;
}
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
Console Output:
ABC
```

I want to know some details how a thread_fork() function can return two different values using C Context library (setcontext(), getContext, etc).

Comment: Is `thread_fork` implemented by you? Where is the implementation?

Comment: I need to implement thread_fork() function using C library function getcontext(), setcontext(), swapcontext() etc. But I am unable to figure out a way to return two different values as mentioned above.

Comment: Why do you think you can do it using these functions? They are good switching the execution context, but how do you intend schedule it?

Comment: @Wajih I can't thing of any way of implementing a `fork` equivalent. The `fork` function is pretty complicated and it benefits from the kernel's support. You should rather try to implement more like a `pthread_create` equivalent and enforce some kind of a cooperative policy for thread scheduling. Maybe this would help: http://www.evanjones.ca/software/threading.html